# Cheerio selector after page loaded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to **scrape** a url value of iframe in this website: https://lk21online.digital/nonton-profile-2021-subtitle-indonesia/
When i search iframe from view page source its not found, i think iframe is loaded after page loaded by javascript
Or my selector is wrong?
Please somebody help me to check my selector or what i need to do for my code
Sorry for my poor english...

There is my code:

```
async function getDetail(res, url) {
    try {
        const html = await scraping(res, url)
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const article = $('#site-container #content .gmr-maincontent #primary #main .gmr-box-content #muvipro_player_content_id #player1-tab-content')
        let result = []

        setTimeout(() => {
            article.each(function () {
                const title = $(this).find('.item-article h2').text()
                const watch = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src')

                result.push({
                    title,
                    watch,
                })

            })
            res.json({ result })
        }, 5000)


    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

[this is video iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBZqn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use cheerio for this. Cheerio is not dynamic and just loads whatever html is coming back from the request.

Looking at your webpage, most content is loaded async, so the initial html will be pretty empty.

In addition the video source is lazily loaded when it enters the browser window. So you have to use an actual headless browser to accomplish the task. Here's an example:

```js
// iframeUrl.js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Goto page
  await page.goto("https://lk21online.digital/nonton-profile-2021-subtitle-indonesia/");
  // Scroll down
  page.evaluate((_) => window.scrollBy(0, 1000));
  // Wait a bit
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  // Get the src of the iframe
  const iframeUrl = await page.evaluate(`$("#player1-tab-content iframe").attr("src")`);
  console.log(iframeUrl);
  await browser.close();
  process.exit(0);
})();
```

Comment: it works exactly like i want, thanks for your advice!